# Dynamic Binding subclass functions

Tags: c++, dynamic, binding

Consider this code:

```
class Bas
{
    public:
        virtual void test() = 0;
};
class Sub : public Bas
{
    public:
        void test(){};
        void subfunc(){};
};
int main()
{
    Bas * bs = new Sub();
    bs->test();
    bs->subfunc(); //Gives error
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't polymorphism be used here? I mean, the object bs is of type Bas and Sub, why can only the functions in Bas be used?

Comment: What polymorphism? `subfunc` is not a member of the base class. *"why can only the functions in Bas be used?"* Well, that's the whole point of polymorphism - the client can use a pointer to `Bas`, and any of its methods, without knowing which actual derived class implements them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So this doesn't work when using dynamic binding?

Comment: What is this "dynamic binding" of which you speak? I'm not familiar with the term.

Answer (score 1):

You can get only those function which you define in base class using base class pointer. Your base class does not have `subfunc()` that is why you are getting error.  Following code may work for you

```
class Bas
{
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
    virtual void subfunc(){};
};

class Sub : public Bas
{
public:
    void test(){};
    void subfunc(){};
};

int main()
{
    Bas * bs = new Sub();
    bs->test();
    bs->subfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism does not work for subfunc because it is not a virtual method in the base class.

[Polymorphism (subtyping in this case)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) will only work for virtual methods that are overriden in the base class. The compiler adds a vtable to each class with that virtual method, so that the correct method is called at runtime (see [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)).

Add a virtual subfunc with no implementation to Bas class.

```
 class Bas
{
    public:
        virtual void test() = 0;

        virtual void subfunc() = 0; //add this
};
```

Comment: This answer only shows how to make the code compile. It doesn't address the OP's question of why the original code did not work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the `main` function, `bs` is known to have type `Bas`.

If you want that the compiler exploits that it also has the type `Sub` (for example to call `subfunc`), you can upcast `bs` to type `Sub` under the condition of a method that ensures that `bs` really has type `Sub`.

```
class Bas
{
    public:
      virtual void test() = 0;
      virtual bool isSub() const { return false; }
};
class Sub : public Bas
{
    public:
      void test(){};
      virtual bool isSub() const { return true; }
      void subfunc(){};
};
int main()
{
    Bas * bs = new Sub();
    bs->test();
    if (bs->isSub()) {
      assert(dynamic_cast<const Sub*>(bs));
      static_cast<Sub*>(bs)->subfunc();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isSub()` is redundant and serves to accomplish the same job that `dynamic_cast` can accomplish by itself. Don't use `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` together like this. Use `dynamic_cast` alone: `Sub *s = dynamic_cast<Sub*>(bs); if (s) s->subfunc();`

Comment: I agree with you only if you don't want to change `Bas` or if `Bas` should have no knowledge of `Sub`. But sometimes `Sub` is known at the `Bas` level: ex a token returned by a lexer where `Bas` is an abstract token and `Sub` a more concrete one. In fact when the `dynamic_cast` fails, it is likely to be more costly than a call to a virtual method. And you cannot rely on `dynamic_cast` if you compile with the option `-fno-rtti` - you have to disable the assert in this case.

Comment: sure, that is another way to do it. But use either 1) `dynamic_cast` or 2) token+`static_cast`, not 3) token+`dynamic_cast`+`static_cast`, that is overkill.

Comment: Yes I agree. 1) or 2) are sufficient to detect bugs.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't polymorphism be used here?

`subfunc` is not `virtual` and thus does not exist in the object's VMT, so it cannot be reached via a base class pointer.

> I mean, the object bs is of type Bas and Sub, why can only the functions in Bas be used?

The object may be a `Sub` in memory, but the `bs` pointer is pointing at the `Bas` portion of the object.   C++ is a type-safe language, and `subfunc` does not exist in `Bas`, so the compiler cannot reach `subfunc` via a `Bas` pointer.  Think of what would happen if `bs` were pointing at a completely different derived class object and not a `Sub` object at all:

```
class Bas
{
    public:
        virtual ~Bas() {}
        virtual void test() = 0;
};

class Sub1 : public Bas
{
    public:
        void test() {};
        void subfunc() {};
};

class Sub2 : public Bas
{
    public:
        void test() {};
        void somethingElse() {};
};

void doTest(Bas *bs)
{
    b->test(); // OK
    b->subfunc(); // error!
    // exists in s1, but not reachable.
    // does not exist in s2 at all.
}

int main()
{
    Sub1 s1;
    doTest(&s1);

    Sub2 s2;
    doTest(&s2);

    return 0;
}
```

How do you expect the compiler to call `subfunc` when it might not even exist in the object being pointed at?

The whole point of polymorphism is to hide implementations and only expose callable interfaces. `subfunc` is not part of `Bas`'s interface.

If you really want to call `subfunc`, you have to make sure you are dealing with the current object type first, and then adjust the pointer accordingly to reach it.  C++ has `dynamic_cast` for that very purpose:

```
void doTest(Bas *bs)
{
    b->test();
    Sub1 *s1 = dynamic_cast<Sub1*>(b);
    if (s1) s1->subfunc();
    Sub2 *s2 = dynamic_cast<Sub2*>(b);
    if (s2) s1->somethingElse();
}
```